# Simplest way to change which of two sections of Python script code should be run

Tags: python, ide, workflow

I wrote two Python functions for converting RGB colors of an image representing tuples to single integer values using two different approaches.

In order to test if both the approaches deliver the same results it was necessary to frequently switch between the two code sections choosing which one should be run.

Finally I decided to use only one of the approaches, but decided to keep the other one in the script code as it better demonstrates what the code does.

In order to 'switch off' one block of code and 'switch on' another one I have used two different methods: an `if` code block (see one of the functions in the code below) and a triple quoted string.

The first approach (with `if`) makes it necessary to introduce additional indentation to the code and the other one required to move a line with triple quotes from the bottom to the top of the code block with an intermediate triple quotes. Both methods work ok, but ...

Is there a better and more easy way of such switching? Best if it would require to press a key on the keyboard only once in order to switch between the two code blocks?

Here my code:

```
# ======================================================================
''' Conversion functions for single RGB-color values '''
def rgb2int(rgb_tuple):
    if 1: # <<< change to 0 to switch to the else: part of code
        from sys import byteorder as endian
        # endianiness = sys.byteorder # 'little'
        int_rgb = int.from_bytes(bytearray(rgb_tuple), endian) # ,signed=False)
    else: 
        if len(rgb_tuple) == 4: # RGBA tuple
            R,G,B,A = rgb_tuple
        else:
            R,G,B   = rgb_tuple
            A = None
        if A is not None: 
            int_rgb =(     0    ) + A 
        else:
            int_rgb =      0
        int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + B
        int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + G # ! int_rgb<<8 + G == int_rgb<<(8+G) !
        int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + R
    return int_rgb

def int2rgb(int_rgb, alpha=False):
    from sys import byteorder as endian
    tplsize = 4 if alpha else 3
    rgb_tuple = tuple(int_rgb.to_bytes(tplsize, endian)) # ,signed=False))    
    """
    if not alpha: 
        rgb_tuple = (
              int_rgb         & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >>  8 ) & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >> 16 ) & 0xff )
    else: # with alpha channel:
        rgb_tuple = (
              int_rgb         & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >>  8 ) & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >> 16 ) & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >> 24 ) & 0xff )
    """ # <<< move to top to switch to the code block above

    return rgb_tuple

rgb     = (32,253,200,100)
int_rgb = rgb2int(rgb)
rgb_    = int2rgb(int_rgb, alpha=True)
print(rgb, int_rgb, rgb_, sep='\n')
assert rgb == rgb_

rgb     = (32,253,200)
int_rgb = rgb2int(rgb)
rgb_    = int2rgb(int_rgb)
assert rgb == rgb_

# ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('  ---   ') 

    print(rgb)
    print(int_rgb)
    print(rgb_)
    #This gives:

    [32, 253, 200]
    13172000
    [32, 253, 200]
```

UPDATE because of response:

Responding to a comment an explanation why I haven't choose to use two different functions to separate the pieces of code:

*Two separate functions would separate parts of code which belong together as code of one function and makes it necessary to explain in the code that both functions are doing exactly the same in spite of the fact they have different names.*

The use case is to test if two parts of code actually do exactly the same after editing their code in order to decide later which version to use. In the provided case the second code block can be used as an explanation what the other does, so it makes sense to keep it in the function in spite of the fact it won't be used.

Comment: How about writing two separate functions? then you can switch by switching the name of the function.

Comment: Two separate functions would separate parts of code which belong together as code of one function and makes it necessary to explain in the code that both functions are doing the same in spite of the fact they have different names.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using a smart combination of a line comment `'#'` character and triple quotes `"""` it is possible in Python to switch between two code blocks like magic pressing `[Del]` or `[#]` on the keyboard.

See the code below how it is done and enjoy the 'magic'.

```
# ======================================================================
''' Conversion functions for single RGB-color values '''
def rgb2int(rgb_tuple):
    #""" <<< remove or add '#' to 'switch' between the two code blocks
    from sys import byteorder as endian
    # endianiness = sys.byteorder # 'little'
    int_rgb = int.from_bytes(bytearray(rgb_tuple), endian) # ,signed=False)
    """
    if len(rgb_tuple) == 4: # RGBA tuple
        R,G,B,A = rgb_tuple
    else:
        R,G,B   = rgb_tuple
        A = None
    if A is not None: 
        int_rgb =(     0    ) + A 
    else:
        int_rgb =      0
    int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + B
    int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + G # ! int_rgb<<8 + G == int_rgb<<(8+G) !
    int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + R
    # """ # the TRICK is to use a line comment before triple quotes
    return int_rgb

def int2rgb(int_rgb, alpha=False):
    #""" <<< remove or add '#' to 'switch' between the two code blocks
    from sys import byteorder as endian
    tplsize = 4 if alpha else 3
    rgb_tuple = tuple(int_rgb.to_bytes(tplsize, endian)) # ,signed=False))    
    """
    if not alpha: 
        rgb_tuple = (
              int_rgb         & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >>  8 ) & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >> 16 ) & 0xff )
    else: # with alpha channel:
        rgb_tuple = (
              int_rgb         & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >>  8 ) & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >> 16 ) & 0xff,
            ( int_rgb >> 24 ) & 0xff )
    # """ # the TRICK is to use a line comment before triple quotes
    return rgb_tuple


rgb     = (32,253,200,100)
int_rgb = rgb2int(rgb)
rgb_    = int2rgb(int_rgb, alpha=True)
print(rgb, int_rgb, rgb_, sep='\n')
assert rgb == rgb_

rgb     = (32,253,200)
int_rgb = rgb2int(rgb)
rgb_    = int2rgb(int_rgb)
assert rgb == rgb_

# ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('  ---   ') 

    print(rgb)
    print(int_rgb)
    print(rgb_)
    #This gives:

    [32, 253, 200]
    13172000
    [32, 253, 200]
```

Bye the way: **you should avoid using it in your coding eventually except for testing purposes**.

Triple quotes in Python are there to make multiline strings and  docstrings possible and using them as a kind of preprocessing switch isn't 'Pythonic'.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write one function that does two different things. Write *two* functions, each of which does one thing:

```
def rgb2int_v1(rgb_tuple):
    from sys import byteorder as endian
    # endianiness = sys.byteorder # 'little'
    int_rgb = int.from_bytes(bytearray(rgb_tuple), endian) # ,signed=False)
    return int_rgb


def rgb2int_v2(rgb_tuple):
    if len(rgb_tuple) == 4: # RGBA tuple
        R,G,B,A = rgb_tuple
    else:
        R,G,B   = rgb_tuple
        A = None
    if A is not None: 
        int_rgb =(     0    ) + A 
    else:
        int_rgb =      0
    int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + B
    int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + G # ! int_rgb<<8 + G == int_rgb<<(8+G) !
    int_rgb  =   (int_rgb<<8) + R
    return int_rgb
```

Then select which version to use at the beginning of your script:

```
rgb2int = rgb2int_v1 if use_v1 else rgb2int_v2
```

where `use_v1` is a variable you set either by editing the script, or preferably by parsing a command-line option so that you can switch between runs without editing your script each time.

Comment: These two pieces of code are *not* two functions doing different things. The first code block does exactly the same as the second one, so it does not make sense to give a piece of code doing exactly the same  as another one a different name. Choosing the approach with different function names is more complicated than usage of `if 1: ... else:` code block to encapsulate a code block making it easily possible to switch to the other one.

Comment: They have the same *result*; that's not the same as obtaining the result the same way.

Comment: `rgb2int = ...` is the encapsulation of choosing which function to use.

Comment: Yes ... but ... I suppose you are missing to understand the actual intention of: keeping pieces of code directly together where the one piece explains what the other does (or lets to  take a look from another perspective) and the other was written to replace the first one and in the intermediate testing phase both were needed to synchronize their outcomes.

Comment: Just test the solution in the other answer and enjoy the surprising 'magic' Python makes possible by smart combination of triple quoted string and the `#` for line comment.

Comment: That's what comments are for: explaining what code does. There's no reason everything needs to be lumped together into a single function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249712/discussion-between-claudio-and-chepner).